# Vue 2 app running on HTTPS, trying to call (axios) a web sercice on same iis server http, call is https instead in dev tools=

Tags: http, iis, https, vuejs2, axios

Vue 2 app (with okta auth) running on iis dev server HTTPS,

Trying to call (axios) a webApi (.netcore) web service on same iis server http, call is https instead, does it get converted?

I literally hardcoded the axios setup to be HTTP, but when i look in network teb of chrome devtools,

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://studentportal4api.jcdev.org',// see http!!!!
  // Timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
```

and..

```
 return apiClient
    .get('/DoCdssLoginTests', {
      params: {
        sAdName: adName,
      },
      
    })
    .then((response) => {

      if (response.data.errorType == 'Error') {
        dispatch('handleErrorMsg', response)
      } else {
       <snip>          
      }
    })
```

the call it https anyway....

What is converting to https? can I turn it off for testing? (long term it's going to all be https, but I"m trying to get it all up and running for the first time)

[image]

Comment: Since your site itself uses https to connect, all requests from the site will be converted to https by the browser.

Comment: is there a way to turn that off for testing? i want to try to cut the problem in half, by hitting it http, then i KNOW my problem is https not something else. THanks

Comment: You can configure http on site during the test. After testing, convert http to https.

Comment: Chrome is converting my http calls to https, whether I want it to or not, that's actually about 90% of my current problems, stuff that works http, doesn't work https, because I've got a dev cert.